# WPF: Keeping track of relative item positions in ItemsControl/ListBox

Tags: wpf, listbox

Please see the following code.

It creates a `ListBox` with five items. The selected item of the `ListBox` is colored in yellow, previous items (index below selected index) are colored in green and future items (index above selected index) are colored in red.

ItemViewModel.vb

```
Public Class ItemViewModel
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Private _title As String
    Private _isOld As Boolean
    Private _isNew As Boolean

    Protected Overridable Sub OnPropertyChanged(<CallerMemberName> Optional propertyName As String = Nothing)
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName) Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub

    Public Property Title As String
        Get
            Return _title
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _title = value
            Me.OnPropertyChanged()
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property IsOld As Boolean
        Get
            Return _isOld
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            _isOld = value
            Me.OnPropertyChanged()
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property IsNew As Boolean
        Get
            Return _isNew
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            _isNew = value
            Me.OnPropertyChanged()
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

MainViewModel:

```
Public Class MainViewModel
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Private ReadOnly _items As ObservableCollection(Of ItemViewModel)
    Private _selectedIndex As Integer

    Public Sub New()
        _items = New ObservableCollection(Of ItemViewModel)
        _items.Add(New ItemViewModel With {.Title = "Very old"})
        _items.Add(New ItemViewModel With {.Title = "Old"})
        _items.Add(New ItemViewModel With {.Title = "Current"})
        _items.Add(New ItemViewModel With {.Title = "New"})
        _items.Add(New ItemViewModel With {.Title = "Very new"})

        Me.SelectedIndex = 0
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub OnPropertyChanged(<CallerMemberName> Optional propertyName As String = Nothing)
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName) Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Items As ObservableCollection(Of ItemViewModel)
        Get
            Return _items
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Property SelectedIndex As Integer
        Get
            Return _selectedIndex
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _selectedIndex = value
            Me.OnPropertyChanged()

            For index As Integer = 0 To Me.Items.Count - 1
                Me.Items(index).IsOld = (index < Me.SelectedIndex)
                Me.Items(index).IsNew = (index > Me.SelectedIndex)
            Next index
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="200">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}">
                    <TextBlock.Style>
                         <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsOld}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsNew}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBlock.Style>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Window>
```

This works like expected, but I don't like, that the `ItemViewModel` holds the properties `IsOld` and `IsNew` and that the `MainViewModel` is responsible for updating these properties. In my opinion that should be done by the `ListBox`, not by every view model that might be the `DataContext` for my `ListBox`.

I already tried to create two attached properties for `ListBoxItem` and bind to them (like I bound to `IsSelected` for the current item). But I couldn't figure out an event on which I update those attached properties.

Is using these attached properties the way to go? When and/or where do I update those attached properties?
I tried to attach to the `ValueChanged` event of the `ItemsSource` property of the `ListBox` to be able to attach to the `CollectionChanged` event of the underlying collection. But I failed getting the `ListBoxItem` for an item, since these containers are created asynchronously (so I assume). And since the `ListBox` uses a `VirtualizingStackPanel` by default, I wouldn't get a `ListBoxItem` for every item of my underlying collection anyway.

Please keep in mind that the collection of items I bind to is observable and can change. So the `IsOld` and `IsNew` properties have to be updated whenever the source collection itself changes, whenever the content of the source collection changes and whenever the selected index changes.

Or how else can I achieve what I like to achieve?

I didn't flag VB.net on purpose since the question doesn't have anything to do with VB.net and I'm fine with answers in C# as well.

Thank you.

Comment: I didn't flag VB.net on purpose since the question doesn't have anything to do with VB.net and I'm fine with answers in C# as well.

Comment: *But I couldn't figure out an event on which I update those attached properties?* How about the `SelectionChanged` event?

Comment: What about the changes of the `ItemsSource` itself and the changes of the content of the `ItemsSource`?

Comment: There is an `OnItemsChanged` method that you can override. But why can't you just handle the `SelectionChanged` and set the properties of the source objects?

Comment: If my source collection contains 5 items and the 3rd one is selected, then the selection won't change when I add a new item to the collection. So the new item wouldn't get the info that is is new and has to appear in red.

Comment: You need to hook up an event handler for the `CollectionChanged` event of the source collection to be able to detect this. And it requires the source collecton to raise an event.

Comment: I was there but I still don't know where to put the `IsNew` and `IsOld` info. When the `ItemsSource` is set, there are no `ListBoxItems` to put the info into (because these are created asynchronously and only when the items are really visible in the vew port). That's why I was asking if the attached properties to the `ListBoxItems` are a good choice or if there are other ways to achieve my goal.

Comment: For the `ListBox` to be able to set a property of an item, it has to either know the type of the item or at least cast it to some pre-defined interface at runtime and then set the properties.

Comment: And that's what I don't like, I don't want the item of my underlying collection to hold  the info whether they're new or old. I like this info to be held somewhere inside the `ListBox` or at least outside of my items.

Comment: So you want to get rid of the Is* properties from the `ItemViewModel` class? I guess you could define a custom container type with these properties and create a custom `ListBox` control that overrides `GetContainerForItemOverride()`.

Comment: I have to have a look into that. I hope I know the index of the item I create the container for in `GetContainerForItemOverride`.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can achieve this is through an attached behavior. This allows you to keep the display behavior with the `ListBox` and away from your view-model, etc.

First, I created an enum to store the states of the items:

```
namespace WpfApp4
{
    public enum ListBoxItemAge
    {
        Old,
        Current,
        New,
        None
    }
}
```

Next, I created an attached behavior class with two attached properties:

- `IsActive` (`bool`) = Turns on the behavior for the ListBox
- `ItemAge` (`ListBoxItemAge`) = Determines if an item should be displayed in Red, Yellow, Green, etc.

When `IsActive` is set to `True` on a `ListBox`, it will subscribe to the SelectionChanged event and will handle setting each `ListBoxItem`s age.

Here is the code:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApp4
{
    public class ListBoxItemAgeBehavior
    {
        #region IsActive (Attached Property)
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsActiveProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "IsActive",
                typeof(bool),
                typeof(ListBoxItemAgeBehavior),
                new PropertyMetadata(false, OnIsActiveChanged));

        public static bool GetIsActive(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsActiveProperty);
        }

        public static void SetIsActive(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(IsActiveProperty, value);
        }

        private static void OnIsActiveChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!(d is ListBox listBox)) return;

            if ((bool) e.NewValue)
            {
                listBox.SelectionChanged += OnSelectionChanged;
            }
            else
            {
                listBox.SelectionChanged -= OnSelectionChanged;
            }
        }

        private static void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var listBox = (ListBox) sender;

            var selectedIndex = listBox.SelectedIndex;

            SetItemAge(listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(selectedIndex), ListBoxItemAge.Current);

            foreach (var item in listBox.ItemsSource)
            {
                var index = listBox.Items.IndexOf(item);

                if (index < selectedIndex)
                {
                    SetItemAge(listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index), ListBoxItemAge.Old);
                }
                else if (index > selectedIndex)
                {
                    SetItemAge(listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index), ListBoxItemAge.New);
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region ItemAge (Attached Property)
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemAgeProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "ItemAge",
                typeof(ListBoxItemAge),
                typeof(ListBoxItemAgeBehavior),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(ListBoxItemAge.None));

        public static ListBoxItemAge GetItemAge(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (ListBoxItemAge)obj.GetValue(ItemAgeProperty);
        }

        public static void SetItemAge(DependencyObject obj, ListBoxItemAge value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(ItemAgeProperty, value);
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

The XAML looks something like this. This is just a simple example:

```
<ListBox
    local:ListBoxItemAgeBehavior.IsActive="True"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}">
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(local:ListBoxItemAgeBehavior.ItemAge), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" Value="Old">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(local:ListBoxItemAgeBehavior.ItemAge), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" Value="Current">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(local:ListBoxItemAgeBehavior.ItemAge), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" Value="New">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I've created three `DataTrigger`s that look for the value of the `ListBoxItemAgeBehavior.ItemAge` and then set the appropriate `Foreground` color. Since the attached property is set on the ListBoxItem, I'm doing a `RelativeSource` on the binding.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, but did you try this? The calls to `ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex` (`OnSelectionChanged`) of the `ListBox` return `null`/`Nothing` for every index.

Comment: Absolutely. I created a fully running sample project.

Comment: Did you use an out-of-the-box WPF `ListBox`? I had to add a check for `null`/`Nothing` in `GetItemAge` and `SetItemAge` to get it to work, at least partly.
But thank you, I try to go down that road and care for changes in the `ItemsCollection` as well.