# WPF: item container not part of the item collection

Tags: wpf

For [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58339292/wpf-keeping-track-of-relative-item-positions-in-itemscontrol-listbox) I need to figure out the position of every item of a `ListBox` relative to the currently selected item, because I'd like to style the items before the currently selected item different than the items behind the currently selected item (by `Trigger`).

I try different things, one of them is using a `MultiBinding` with a `MultiValueConverter`.

The XAML of the `DataTrigger` looks like this:

```
<DataTrigger Value="True">
    <DataTrigger.Binding>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource rpc}">
            <Binding Path="." RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}" />
            <Binding Path="." RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </DataTrigger.Binding>

    <Setter Property="..." Value="..." />
</DataTrigger>
```

This `DataTrigger` is used in a `Style` that is used inside the `ItemTemplate` of the `ListBox`.

The mentioned `Converter` "rpc" is a `MultiValueConverter`.

If I set a break point inside the `Convert` function of this `MultiValueConverter` I get the `ListBox` instance as the first value and the `ListBoxItem` instance as the second value, so the `MultiBinding` works.

But if I try to figure out the index of the `ListBoxItem` inside the `ItemsCollection` of the `ListBox` by using `listBox.Items.IndexOf(listBoxItem)` I always get -1, as if the `ListBoxItem` is not a member of the `ItemsCollection`.

Even if I try to find out the `ListBoxItem` by checking the `Content` of the items for equality (`listBox.Items.OfType(Of ListBoxItem).FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Content.Equals(listBoxItem.Content)))`, I won't get a `ListBoxItem`.

Why is that so?
And how else can I get the index of the `ListBoxItem` if not by `IndexOf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting -1 because the `Items` collection doesn't contain any `ListBoxItem` elements, but rather the actual contents of the `ListBoxItem`.

Try this:

```
var index = listBox.Items.IndexOf(listBoxItem.Content);
```

Comment: Thank you. That's it. I thought the `ItemCollection` would contain the `ListBoxItems`, not the actual items.